# Gulp 4 multiple tasks on same source and in series

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-4

I edit my gulpfile like below:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('**/*.html', gulp.series('htmlcomb'));
    gulp.watch('css/**/*.scss', gulp.series('csscomb'));
    gulp.watch('css/**/*.scss', gulp.series('cssmin'));        
    gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', gulp.series('jsmin'));
});
```

But when I run gulp watch it stops after csscomb. When I edit a scss file. It only comb on it.

I can run htmlcomb, jsmin and (cssbomb + cssmin) as async. But I need to run cssmin after csscomb.

Answer (score 0):

If you want csscomb to run before cssmin just use:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('**/*.html', gulp.series('htmlcomb'));

    gulp.watch('css/**/*.scss', gulp.series('csscomb', 'cssmin'));

    gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', gulp.series('jsmin'));
});
```

Actually, if you are using gulp4.0 your functions could be of the form:

```
function csscomb() {
  return gulp.src(…...)
    .pipe.....)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(…...));
}
```

so your watch tasks are calling functions - not tasks - and would look like this:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('**/*.html', gulp.series(htmlcomb));

    gulp.watch('css/**/*.scss', gulp.series(csscomb, cssmin));

    gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', gulp.series(jsmin));
});
```